# React - Events in same class with parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Reactable to create a table. When clicked on the action box, I want a box with extra information about that row to appear by changing the style.
This is my code so far:

```
var SelLines  = new Object();
var Home = React.createClass({

    handleClick: function(e) {
        console.log("##Clicked##");
    },  

    render: function() {    
        var tableRows = Data.map(function(tableRow) {
            console.log(tableRow);
            SelLines[tableRow.ID] = false;
            console.log(SelLines);
            if (SelLines[tableRow.ID]) {
                return (
                    <Tr>
                        <Td column="ID">{tableRow.ID}</Td>
                        <Td column="DESCRIPTION">{tableRow.DESCRIPTION}</Td>
                        <Td className="cellSelected" column="ACTION"><a onClick={SelLines[tableRow.ID] = true;Home.handleClick}>{tableRow.ACTION}</a></Td>
                         //// = true;Home.h ## not working
                    </Tr>
                );
            } else {
                return (
                    <Tr>
                        <Td column="ID">{tableRow.ID}</Td>
                        <Td column="DESCRIPTION">{tableRow.DESCRIPTION}</Td>
                        <Td className="cellNotSelected" column="ACTION"><a onClick={Home.handleClick}>{tableRow.ACTION}</a></Td>
                    </Tr>
                );
            }
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Table className="table" id="table">
                        <Thead>
                            <Th column="ID">
                                <strong className="ID-header">ID</strong>
                            </Th>
                            <Th column="DESCRIPTION">
                                <em className="DESCRIPTION-header">DESCRIPTION</em>
                            </Th>
                            <Th column="ACTION">
                                <em className="ACTION-header">ACTION</em>
                            </Th>
                       </Thead>
                       {tableRows}
                   </Table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

How can I pass a parameter to handleClick?

Comment: `onClick={SelLines[tableRow.ID] = true;Home.handleClick}` is the equivalent to `{onClick: SelLines[tableRow.ID] = true;Home.handleClick}`. That's simply invalid JavaScript. The `{...}` can only contains *expressions*.

Comment: Can you fix your formatting? Also, you are setting `SelLines[tableRow.ID] = false` in your `map` function so it will never get to your `if true` condition.

Comment: @PL I fixed your formatting for you. Next time please post well-formatted code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to prepend arguments to be called with when the function is invoked.

```
<a onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, tableRow.ID)}>{tableRow.ACTION}</a>

handleClick: function(tableRowId, e) {
    SelLines[tableRowId] = true;
    console.log("##Clicked##", tableRowId);
}
```

Since you are rendering inside a `map()` callback you also have to bind the callback:

```
var tableRows = Data.map(function(tableRow){
    // ...
}.bind(this));
```

---

Or if you use ES6 you can write arrow functions to avoid needing to `bind`:

```
var tableRows(Data.map((tableRow) => {
    // ...
});
```

And you can write an inline arrow function as your handler which calls through to another function with some arguments:

```
<a onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(tableRow.ID)}>{tableRow.ACTION}</a>
```

Comment: That works when I call it in the return of home, but not in he return of tableRows - how can I bind it to the parent item?

Comment: I missed your `map` function because of how it's formatted. You need to either `bind` your map callback or use an arrow function.